# Logitech K380 fn + opt + cmd + L puts my Mac to sleep

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, sleep

I have used the keyboard combination `control` + `option` + `command` + `L` on a daily basis for years. I recently bought the Logitech K380 not noticing that it swaps the position of the `Fn` and `Ctrl` keys (when compared to a standard Mac keyboard).

Due to years of muscle memory, I regularly now press `Fn` + `Opt` + `Cmd` + `L` on the K380, which seems to instantly put my Mac to sleep. Is there any way for me to disable this so that my computer does not go to sleep when I accidentally press this combination?

Also, interestingly, the same combination (`Fn` + `Opt` + `Cmd` + `L`) on my Mac's built-in keyboard does NOT cause my computer to go to sleep.

Comment: Fn keys are combined before leaving the keyboard, so to see what it's doing, get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & compare outputs from the two keyboards. That will at least give you a start as to what actual key command is being sent.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately Key Codes does not log this particular combination. I suspect perhaps the triggering of OSX sleep supersedes Key Codes logging.

Comment: Ugh, that's irritating. I'm afraid I'm not sure what to try next. That key combo does nothing on my Mac.